# What did LEGO bricks look like in the past?

Tags: piece-information, vintage

How did LEGO bricks look like in the olden days?

Can you also show me the bottom of a LEGO brick from the olden days?

Comment: Hi Grace and welcome to Bricks.SE! Could you please clarify what do you mean by "olden days"?

Answer (score 8):

The earliest LEGO bricks were made in 1949, and they had completely empty undersides with vertical notches in two of their sides for [attaching windows, doors and decorative cardboard inserts](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Wh5hpd1GU1Y/VU86CGs_OtI/AAAAAAAAFn0/RSlZ0xsq9as/s1600/FirstVersions_LEGO_windows.png):
[image]

Then in 1958 (or 1961, depending on the country) the form known today was adopted, with tubes on the bottom and without notches:

[image]

Comment: 1961 is when the patent in the US was issued, in Denmark (LEGO is a danish company) the patent was granted in 1958 (and in many other countries was probably granted earlier than 1961 too), so LEGO bricks looked like what we know today some years earlier than you said.